# A tiny and simple script fail and this is the output "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, shell-script

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS="
"

command="ls /tmp"

for file in `$command`;
do
    echo $file
done
```

And the output is:

```
$ ./test.sh 
./test.sh: line 17: ls /tmp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Check your path. Put " $> echo env " in your program. It is trying to run the file from wherever you are executing the script from. " > cd /tmp/ " to change working directory.

Comment: Ah. Command substitution. Well done.

Comment: Thanks to all. I found other solution: #!/bin/bash
command="ls /tmp"
result=`$command`

IFS="
"
for file in $result;
do
 echo $file
done
IFS=" "

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that bash won't execute variables that contain spaces correctly because you have set `$IFS` to a newline. This causes it to attempt to execute the whole thing as one command instead of taking the first word as a command and passing the rest as arguments.

If you were to run this with `strace`, instead of seeing this:

```
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "/tmp"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
                   ---    -----
                    |       |-------------> 2nd argument 
                    |---------------------> 1st argument, the command to run.
```

You would see that the 1st argument is `ls /tmp` instead of `ls` alone, and that is something the system cannot execute.

Your script will actually work as you expect if you don't set the `IFS` variable. However, you really should never use `ls` to iterate over the output of a command unless you *know* that the output will never contain spaces or other strange characters. To illustrate:

```
$ touch 'file name with spaces'
$ for i in $(ls ./); do echo "$i"; done
file
name
with
spaces
```

The correct way is to use one of these:

```
$ for i in *; do echo "i is: $i"; done
i is: file name with spaces
$ find . -type f | while IFS= read -r i; do echo "i is: $i"; done
i is: ./file name with spaces
```

If you really, really want to use `ls`, at least use it with a while loop. That will still break on various things but at least it can deal with spaces:

```
$ ls | while read i; do echo "i is: $i"; done
i is: file name with spaces
```

Finally, to be able to deal with *any* file name, including those with newlines, backslashes, spaces or anything else. Use:

```
  $ find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do echo "i is: $i"; done
  i is: ./file name with spaces
```

Comment: Whenever I see a fat hair, I have to split it. :) “… `ls /tmp` … is something the system cannot execute.” No, if there is a subdirectory named `ls ` (i.e., lowercase L, lowercase S, space) and a program or script called `tmp` in that directory, then _that_ program will be executed if the shell sees a `ls /tmp` command with IFS set to newline only.

Comment: @G-Man and _that's_ the detail I had missed. Yup, that will work indeed. I deleted our previous comments since your first one would have been enough had I read it carefully.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that you can never pass a variable to a command? I'm trying to perform a 'mv "tmp/$FOO_* $FOO/"' where $FOO is the prefix to a filename, where I can create a directory called $FOO and mv any file with that prefix to its own directory. I don't know those file prefixes before executing the script. Is there no dynamic way to handle this? I don't understand how 'echo "$FOO"' can work, but 'ls "$FOO"' can't.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `IFS` part.

`$IFS` is the internal field separator variable of `bash`. You line in the script causes `bash` to separate the fields only in newlines and not in the default (space, tab and newline). `ls` gives the output separated in tabs.

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

command="ls /tmp"

for file in `$command`;
do
    echo $file
done
```

Comment: The tabs are not the issue here. First of all, a simple `ls` has no tabs in the output, it just prints file names, where would the tab be? In any case, I don't know of any cases where `ls` will print tabs. The problem is indeed the IFS but for different reasons, the command is not split correctly by bash.